# How to limit number of returned objects in group query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongodb database with several hundred records, each with a value for the field "pauseTime." I would like to count the number of records for each value of pauseTime. But I want to limit the query to the documents where pauseTime greater than 50 and less than 150.

I got so far as counting the number of each each value for pauseTime.

This is a record of the database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca74a95a094b08e97bd1278"),
    "duration" : NumberInt(857),
    "videoUrl" : "https://vimeo.com/3766858",
    "pauseTime" : NumberInt(493),
    "contentType" : "Comment",
    "comment" : "vsvdbdbdab adb",
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

This is my query so far:

```
db.getCollection("videocomments").aggregate([ {"$group" : {_id:"$pauseTime", count:{$sum:1}}} ])
```

It returns:

```
{ "_id" : 480, "count" : 8 }
{ "_id" : 437, "count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 51, "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 434, "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 750, "count" : 9 } 
...
```

How do I proceed to limit the "_id" (i.e., pauseTime) to 50 < x < 150?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`$lte`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) and [**`$gte`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) query operator with the `pauseTime`

```
db.getCollection("videocomments").aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "pauseTime": { "$gte": 50, "$lte": 150 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$pauseTime",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```